# Find all except a specific key:value pair Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Does anyone know how to find all in a collection but exclude one key:value pair?

My collection looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "HsM4HpwrYAXh2PJeN",
  "contact" : [ {
    "emailAddress" : "harry@potter.com",
    "someContact" : "No",
    "creationDate" : "N/A",
    "hardBounceBack" : "N/A",
    "unsubscribed" : "No"
  } ]
}
```

I have 500 of these contacts in my “contacts” collection. I want to return all contacts except for contacts with “unsubscribed”:”No”. I have tried $nin $ne and $where cannot find the right way to return everything except for objects where "unsubscribed":"No".

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested array of objects so you need to use `$elemMatch:` in combination with `$ne:`

```
collection.find({ contact: { $elemMatch: { unsubscribed: { $ne: "No" }}}});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the nesting earlier. It helped me to reformat the object ;)